# Нужно остановить итерацию

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно создать функцию-генератор, которая будет выводить случайные значения из заданного
диапазона. В генератор подаётся нижняя граница диапазона, верхняя граница и число итераций.
Также нужно прописать условие: если значение верхней границы было выведено два раза, то
после этого работа генератора заканчивается.

Написанный код:

```
def func_gen(start, end, num):
    lst = [random.randint(start, end) for i in range(start + end)]
    lst1 = random.sample(lst, num)
    if lst1[0] == start and lst1[1] == start:
        raise StopIteration
    else:
        yield lst1
a = func_gen(1, 8, 3)
for i in a :
    print(i)
```

Описание проблемы: я сомневаюсь, что эта функция является генератором и она правильно работает под условие, не могли бы вы это проверить? + ответ выводится списком, хотя есть цикл for  в конце....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Является ли она генератором?

```py
# добавляем в код в конце, чтобы узнать, что же такое a
print(a)
```

Результат:

```py
<generator object func_gen at 0x7febb4ac9050>
```

Да, ответ функции является генератором

#### 2. Правильно ли работает генератор?

Определённо, нет. Во-первых он возвращает не кортеж значений, а кортеж, который содержит список значений. Убедимся в этом:

```py
# добавим в код в конце, чтобы узнать, что же возвращает этот генератор
print(tuple(a))
```

Результат:

```py
([3, 3, 3, 1, 1],)
```

Во-вторых у вас неправильно был задан генератор `lst`. Раз генерировать нужно `num` чисел, то и аргументом `range` должен быть `num`, а не `start+end`
В-третьих элементы с максимальным значением ведь не обязательно идут подряд, и не обязательно первыми, поэтому проверка выполнена неверно.

#### 3. Как сделать, чтобы было правильно?

```py
import random
def func_gen(start, end, num):
    lst = []
    for i in range(num):
        lst.append(random.randint(start, end))
        count = 0
        for elem in lst:
            if elem == end:
                count += 1
        if count >= 2:
            break
    for elem in lst:
        yield elem

a = func_gen(1, 2, 5)

# убедимся, что a - генератор, а также проверим, что он возвращает
print(a)
print(tuple(a))
```

Вот пример двух результатов:

```py
# верхняя граница была добавлена два раза - больше элементов не добавлялось
<generator object func_gen at 0x7f6c699e3050>
(1, 1, 2, 2)
```

```py
# верхняя граница не была добавлена два раза - элементов 5. Ровно столько, сколько указано при обращении к функции
<generator object func_gen at 0x7f9fb8160050>
(1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def func_gen(start, end, num):
    count = 0
    for _ in range(num):
        r = randint(start, end)
        if r == start:
            count += 1
        yield r

        if count == 2:
            raise StopIteration
```